# Cascade Delete in Postgres: Delete from Child & Parent Tables with Saved IDs from Child

Tags: sql, postgresql

In Postgres I have two tables where I need to clear out some data with a Cascade Delete:

```
- PARTICIPANTS_T: has a foreign key USER_ID on USERS_T.ID
- USERS_T
```

The first step is to delete from PARTICIPANTS_T where a criterion is satisfied, e.g.

`delete from PARTICIPANTS_T where VALID_FLAG = 'Y';`

The second is to delete from USERS_T the rows whose IDs were referenced in the prior Delete.

`delete from USERS_T where ID = [..from Step 1..]`

How to do the Cascade Delete in Postgres?

I've thought about saving in a variable: `select INTO`,

`if exists drop table user_ids; --This syntax is wrong
select id into user_ids from users_t where id in (
        select user_id from participants_t where valid_flag = 'Y');`

but that's inconvenient because `user_ids` becomes a separate table that needs to be maintained. My syntax above is incorrect. Can anyone give a complete repeatable script with these 2 steps?

Comment: you coulld have used cascade on delete !!! on table1

Answer (score 1):

This worked: begin/commit around the cascade delete:

```
begin;
delete from participants_t where valid_flag = 'Y';
delete from users_t where id in (
            select user_id from participants_t where valid_flag = 'Y');       
commit;
```

Answer (score 0):

I do cascading delete from N tables using `WITH` structure.
In your case I would suggest:

```
WITH participants AS (
    DELETE FROM PARTICIPANTS_T participants
    WHERE VALID_FLAG='Y'
    RETURNING participants.ID AS del_ids
    )
DELETE FROM USERS_T users
WHERE users.ID in (SELECT del_ids FROM participants);
```

Personally I've used this query by adding another table (3 tables were connected by ID). To use this solution with more tables you can do something like:

```
WITH participants AS (
    DELETE FROM PARTICIPANTS_T participants
    WHERE VALID_FLAG='Y'
    RETURNING participants.ID AS del_ids
    )
    , additional_table AS (
    DELETE FROM ADDITIONAL_TABLE add_table
    WHERE add_table.ID in (SELECT del_ids FROM participants)
    )
DELETE FROM USERS_T users
WHERE users.ID in (SELECT del_ids FROM participants);
```

One thing to remember - query is executing from UP to DOWN, so first you need to delete tables which keeps `FOREIGN_KEY`. The last table should be table which keep joining key as a `PRIMARY_KEY`.